# Bessel sequence, uniformly minimal, separated

Tags: banach-spaces, fa.functional-analysis

Is every unit norm Bessel sequence in a Hilbert space a finite union of separated ones? Is every unit norm separated sequence a finite union of uniformly minimal (minimal with uniformly bounded biorthogonal vectors) ones?

Comment: It might be worth defining these terms...

Comment: Unit norm means each vector is of norm 1. Separated means that there is a constant $c>0$ s.t. the distance between any two vectors is $>c$. Minimal means that none of the vectors is in the closed span of the others.  

Comment: And a Bessel sequence?

Comment: $f_n$ is a Bessel sequence if $\sum|<f|f_n>|^2\leq \|f\|^2$ for all vectors $f$.

Comment: instead of $\leq \|f\|^2$ it should be $\leq C\|f\|^2$. Sorry. 

Answer (score 2):

Your questions are weakenings of the Feichtinger conjecture, which is equivalent to the Kadison-Singer problem. See

http://www.aimath.org/WWN/kadisonsinger/FrameProblems.pdf

and the references therein.

Your second question is Problem 2.2 there.

The questions themselves are not obvious ones.  Why did you ask them?